# Why do large values become negative?

Tags: c

Why do I get negative values for high numbers? I use `long` as data type but it still doesn't work:

```
int main() {

    int n = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    int i = 6;
    long a[100000];
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 1;
    a[2] = 2;
    a[3] = 7;
    a[4] = 20;
    a[5] = 61;

    for (i = 6; i < 100000; i = i + 1) {  
        a[i] = (2 * (a[i - 1]) + (3 * (a[i - 2])));  
    }  

    printf ("%ld", a[n]);

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably overflowing since it looks like there's exponential growth in your values.

Comment: Always good to post your 1) input 2) output 3) expected output.

Comment: You should put a `printf("%d %ld", i, a[i])` inside the loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "higher numbers"? Is a higher number 20 or 20,000,000?

Comment: Try printing the values of all the elements up to `n`. You'll see that they get bigger and biffer, and eventually get too big for `long` and overflow.

Comment: The short answer to your question is this: If you think about an old automobile odometer, it rolls over from 999999 to 0. You can define negative one as "a number you can add one to and get zero". So too large numbers and negative numbers overlap in many representation schemes with fixed space.

Answer (score 2):

The series you compute in your program grows exponentially. The n-th term is approximately proportional to 3<sup>n</sup>. You cannot compute more than a couple dozen of terms with regular integer arithmetics: even with 64-bit `long` or preferably `long long`, you are limited to 2<sup>64</sup>, which is way too small.

When the computed result exceeds the range of `long`, the behavior is undefined as per the C Standard, but what happens on your computer's CPU is the bit-pattern of the overflowing result has its topmost bit set, making it a negative number, which `printf()` converts and outputs.

Using `double` type would get you a little farther, but not much.

You would need to use a bignum package to compute the 100000th element of the series, a huge number with 47711 digits: approximately `3.3374285355760036736472859762244e47710`.

Here is an implementation in javascript which you can test with QuickJS or a your favorite navigator's javascript console:

```js
function fib23(n) {
    var a, b, c = 0n;
    if (n > 0) {
        b = c;
        c = 1n;
        for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = 2n * b + 3n * a;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Signed integer representations (usually) reserve the uppermost bit for the sign.  For an imaginary 3-bit type, they go something like this:

```
bit pattern    two's complement    ones' complement    sign-magnitude
-----------    ----------------    ----------------    --------------
        000                   0                   0                 0
        001                   1                   1                 1
        010                   2                   2                 2
        011                   3                   3                 3
        100                  -4                  -3                -0
        101                  -3                  -2                -1
        110                  -2                  -1                -2
        111                  -1                  -0                -3
```

What's happening is you're trying to store a value that's too large to represent as a non-negative signed integer and the uppermost bit is getting set, causing it to be interpreted as a negative number; IOW, signed integer overflow.

The behavior on signed integer overflow in C is *undefined*, meaning the implementation doesn't have to handle it in any particular way.  It doesn't have to throw an exception, it doesn't have to issue any kind of runtime diagnostic, etc.  In your case, it's just kind of letting the overflow happen, and all bets are off when you try to use that value.

Your series grows *very* large *very* quickly - I've taken your code and rewritten it a bit to output the values at each stage (also eliminated the array, since I don't care about storing the values).  I also added a condition to the `for` loop to stop when the next operation would overflow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main( void )
{
  long cur = 0;
  long pre_1 = 61;
  long pre_2 = 20;

  int i = 6;

  printf( "LONG_MAX = %ld\n", LONG_MAX );

  for ( i = 6; LONG_MAX - (2 * pre_1 + 3 * pre_2) > cur && i < 100000; i++ )
  {
    cur = 2 * pre_1 + 3 * pre_2;
    printf( "i = %3d: cur = %20ld, pre_1 = %20ld, pre_2 = %20ld\n", i, cur, pre_1, pre_2 ); 
    pre_2 = pre_1;
    pre_1 = cur;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
LONG_MAX = 9223372036854775807
i =   6: cur =                  182, pre_1 =                   61, pre_2 =                   20
i =   7: cur =                  547, pre_1 =                  182, pre_2 =                   61
i =   8: cur =                 1640, pre_1 =                  547, pre_2 =                  182
i =   9: cur =                 4921, pre_1 =                 1640, pre_2 =                  547
i =  10: cur =                14762, pre_1 =                 4921, pre_2 =                 1640
i =  11: cur =                44287, pre_1 =                14762, pre_2 =                 4921
i =  12: cur =               132860, pre_1 =                44287, pre_2 =                14762
i =  13: cur =               398581, pre_1 =               132860, pre_2 =                44287
i =  14: cur =              1195742, pre_1 =               398581, pre_2 =               132860
i =  15: cur =              3587227, pre_1 =              1195742, pre_2 =               398581
i =  16: cur =             10761680, pre_1 =              3587227, pre_2 =              1195742
i =  17: cur =             32285041, pre_1 =             10761680, pre_2 =              3587227
i =  18: cur =             96855122, pre_1 =             32285041, pre_2 =             10761680
i =  19: cur =            290565367, pre_1 =             96855122, pre_2 =             32285041
i =  20: cur =            871696100, pre_1 =            290565367, pre_2 =             96855122
i =  21: cur =           2615088301, pre_1 =            871696100, pre_2 =            290565367
i =  22: cur =           7845264902, pre_1 =           2615088301, pre_2 =            871696100
i =  23: cur =          23535794707, pre_1 =           7845264902, pre_2 =           2615088301
i =  24: cur =          70607384120, pre_1 =          23535794707, pre_2 =           7845264902
i =  25: cur =         211822152361, pre_1 =          70607384120, pre_2 =          23535794707
i =  26: cur =         635466457082, pre_1 =         211822152361, pre_2 =          70607384120
i =  27: cur =        1906399371247, pre_1 =         635466457082, pre_2 =         211822152361
i =  28: cur =        5719198113740, pre_1 =        1906399371247, pre_2 =         635466457082
i =  29: cur =       17157594341221, pre_1 =        5719198113740, pre_2 =        1906399371247
i =  30: cur =       51472783023662, pre_1 =       17157594341221, pre_2 =        5719198113740
i =  31: cur =      154418349070987, pre_1 =       51472783023662, pre_2 =       17157594341221
i =  32: cur =      463255047212960, pre_1 =      154418349070987, pre_2 =       51472783023662
i =  33: cur =     1389765141638881, pre_1 =      463255047212960, pre_2 =      154418349070987
i =  34: cur =     4169295424916642, pre_1 =     1389765141638881, pre_2 =      463255047212960
i =  35: cur =    12507886274749927, pre_1 =     4169295424916642, pre_2 =     1389765141638881
i =  36: cur =    37523658824249780, pre_1 =    12507886274749927, pre_2 =     4169295424916642
i =  37: cur =   112570976472749341, pre_1 =    37523658824249780, pre_2 =    12507886274749927
i =  38: cur =   337712929418248022, pre_1 =   112570976472749341, pre_2 =    37523658824249780
i =  39: cur =  1013138788254744067, pre_1 =   337712929418248022, pre_2 =   112570976472749341
i =  40: cur =  3039416364764232200, pre_1 =  1013138788254744067, pre_2 =   337712929418248022
```

`LONG_MAX` is the largest value that can be represented as a signed `long`, and the 41st term in your series would exceed that value.

Frankly, you're not going to be able to compute this series using native integral types.  I'm not even sure you'd be able to do it with native floating point types.   You'll need to use a third-party library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).